# How to detect and log error before StackOverflowException caught

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

My server has a `StackOverflowException`. It has over 20,000 lines of code and I cant find where it is thrown... Because try / catch is not working I can't get the error... Is there any way I can get the error logs? `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` is not logging it so... How can I detect it and log errors before it crashes my server? You can too suggest something how I can find that `StackOverflowException` :)

**I'm using .NET Framework 4.5**

UnhandledExceptionEventHandler code:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Program.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs);
private static void UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Image:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Well, if you have an SO error (no pun), you most likely have some recursive call going on that is not exiting.  Can't you debug it?

Comment: I run it on VPS and i dont currently want more RAM usage and possible it stucks other errors so thats bad. Is it possible run another porgram or i can only debug it using visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't. `StackOverflowException` is one of the few exceptions that you cannot catch.

If the exception happens in your own code, the best solution is to convert your algorithm from a recursive call into one that uses a heap-allocated `Stack<T>` to track depth state and which also allows you to catch cases where the stack's capacity exceeds a threshold (`if( stack.Count >= 4000 ) break;`.

```
enum Result {
    Found,
    NotFound,
    Aborted
}

public static Result DepthFirstSearch(Node node) {

    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    stack.Push( node );

    while( stack.Count > 0 ) {

        Node n = stack.Pop();
        if( IsNodeWeWant( n ) ) return Result.Found;

        foreach(Node child in n.Children) stack.Push( child );

        if( stack.Count >= 4000 ) return Result.Aborted;

    }
    return Result.NotFound;
}
```

If you feel you must use recursive calls, then add an additional integer parameter to your methods called "depth" (that increases for each recursive call). Within your function you can then check how deep you are and break before you get a stack-overflow.

Example:

```
enum Result {
    Found,
    NotFound,
    Aborted
}

public static Result DepthFirstSearch(Node node, Int32 depth) {

    if( depth >= 4000 ) return Result.Aborted;

    if( IsNodeWeWant( node ) ) return Result.Found;

    foreach(Node child in node.Children) {
        Result result = DepthFirstSearch( child, depth + 1 );
        if( result != Result.NotFound ) return result; // return Found or Aborted
    }
}
```

However, if the exception happens outside your code (and you have no means to validate the data to abort the operation before you enter it) then your only option is to create a child process that hosts the buggy code. You can use some form of IPC or shared-memory for communication (though you can't directly share POCOs, at least not without serialization).

Comment: How i use that Stack<T>?

Comment: @user3290224 I have updated my answer with examples.

Comment: I copy & paste that example and i get errors: Error 1: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) | Error 2: The name 'IsNodeWeWant' does not exist in the current context |Error 3: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.Result' is less accessible than method 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.DepthFirstSearch(Node, int)

Comment: I search internet and "node" support 3.0 and lover.. My program uses 4.5

Comment: @user3290224 Don't copy and paste my code. My code is an example of how would you implement the algorithm. `Node` is not a real class, but used to demonstrate how you might perform depth-first traversal in a safe manner against an arbitrary graph node structure.

Comment: Anyway i found that stackoverflowexception :)

Answer (score 1):

Per [SOException documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it suggests to put a recursion counter in your recursive call.  Pick a value for all your recursive call that seems like it would be too high to ever reach with correct logic, say 10,000 next deep.  When you detect that number that high, log the function name, state of program, stack for the function, and then use it to debug the issue of why it gets so high.